# Configure NFSv4 to allow different users read-write access

Tags: file-permissions, nfs4

I have an NFSv4 server (CentOS). I want to export a particular directory to two different machines (one CentOS and one Ubuntu), where users of the same uid and gid need read-write access to the mounted directory. The GID and UID are the on the clients are the same as on the server, but the user names are different.

When I try using `gid=,uid=` in the `/etc/fstab` I get mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified. messages in `/var/log/messages` are

`nfsidmap[12817]: nss_getpwnam: name 'apprepo' not found in domain 'sagrid.ac.za'`

`apprepo` is the user name which owns the files on the server. `sagrid.ac.za` is of course the domain of our machines.

Comment: As somewhat explained in this [related answer](http://serverfault.com/a/713659/37681) nfs4 no longer relies on uid and gid *numbers* but uses user and group *names* and since those are different between your nfs server and client you need to create a mapping in idmapd

Comment: Hi @HBruijn, and thanks for the input. Yes, this idmapd configuration was (and still is) my problem. I was not able to translate the documentation into a working configuration. 
Since I'm not using NIS or KRB, I wasn't sure  how to write the rpcidm configuration file to say something like : 
 - turn _this name_ on the remote machine into _this name_ on the server. 
I have _not_ resolved this yet, but reverted to NFS3. Since I only have 2 machines I don't think performance won't be an issue... but I would still like to have a working NFS4 confg.

Answer (score 1):

you can enforce nfs client and server to use numeric ids by

```
echo Y > /sys/module/nfs/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping
```

on the client and server

Comment: I did try this, but got the error
`nfsidmap[12817]: nss_getpwnam: name 'apprepo' not found in domain 'sagrid.ac.za'`
There is clearly something wrong with the config, but in a different part. Basically, how do I add the right name to the right domain ?

Comment: id you restart the client? It may sill have cached values